# How to force a refresh of a SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, property-wrapper-published

I have a button with a `.disabled()` condition that's a computed property of my `ObservableObject` model class.  This means I can't make it `@Published`.

Something like this:

```
class MyModel : ObservableObject {
    var isDisabled: Bool {
        if ... {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsNewsSubscriptionsView : View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyModel

    var body: some View {
        ...

        Button("Save") {
            Task {
                // Saves to backend asynchronously, then updates MyModel which changes isDisabled.
            }
        }
        .disabled(model.isDisabled)
    }
}
```

At some point `isDisabled` is `false`.  When the button is tapped something is saved asynchronously after which `MyModel` is updated which will result in `isDisabled` to become `true`.

Because `isDisabled` is not `@Published`, the button does not update once `isDisabled` becomes `true`.

How can I trigger the refresh of a SwiftUI `View`, in this case `Button` explicitly from within a `Task`?

Comment: What are you checking in your if ... ?  Is it checking the value of another property?

Comment: @vacawama What's being checked (combination of backend reply and other properties) is out of scope.  Problem is that `isDisabled` does not cause the `Button` to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```
model.objectWillChange.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try making the property stored instead of computed, that way you can use @Published

Comment: Although this doesn't help me, it's a valid suggestion.